# Pages from Razor Class Library not found by ASP.net core 2.2 web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, razor-class-library

Razor pages from Razor Class Library are not found by webapp, eventhough the library is referenced.

error thrown is (left out some names with ****):

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type '****.Workbench.Pages.IndexModel' 
from assembly '****', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Hi all,

I try to use a Razor class library in my ASP.NET core 2.2 web app to store the razor pages in so they can be reused someplace else.

I looked up some tutorials and it seems pretty straight forward:
1. create a Razor class Library
2. create an asp.net core webapp
3. reference the library in webapp
4. run and the page should be found

What I did is removed the Pages folder from the webapp and put the entire structure in the Razor Class Library. According to the tutorials the only thing needed to make it work is reference the library but it seems something else is needed or I am just doing something wrong.

thx for the input!

Comment: That's a runtime exception that complains the assembly isn't there. Did you deploy it as well? How did you publish/deploy the web app?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos they reside in the same solution and I see the .dll in the bin.
The views reside in project/library ****.Workbench.Views, but I see the webapp tries to look for the views in ****.Workbench, so this is wrong. I need to update routings?

Comment: Yeah. That's not an issue with finding the page, it's an issue with finding the page model, `IndexModel`, in your case. Did you change the class name perhaps in your codebehind for the `Index` page?

Comment: @Chris Pratt I did rename from Page1Model to IndexModel, but it is trying to lookup the pagemodel in the wrong assembly ****.Workbench instead of ****.Workbench.Views

Comment: `Views` is not part of the assembly. It's a folder.

Comment: @Chris Pratt in my case it is an assembly: ****.Workbench.Views, I changed the name to ****.Workbench.UI, but still same issue